# Expressão Regulares

Tags: java, regex

Tenho uma aplicação que lê uma string e precisa detectar parâmetros contidos na string. O parâmetro tem o seguinte padrão `<<<.texto>>>` (`<` e `>` fazem parte do parâmetro).

Consegui fazer uma expressão para capturar os parâmetros corretos. Mas também é necessários identificar os parâmetros incorretos (erros provocados na digitação pelo usuário). Ex.: `<texto>>>`, `<<Texto>>>`, `Texto>>>>` e etc.

Expressão para os parâmetros corretos: `(\\<{3}(\\w+)\\>{3})+`

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Não seria só fazer um `if !correto`?

Comment: Pode sim, tem como ajudar na montagem do IF ?

Comment: Veja se a resposta do Yure atende, eu faria algo parecido

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Não tinha visto.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public class Validator {

  public static boolean validarTexto(String texto) {
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<{3}(\\w+)\\>{3}");
     Matcher retorno = p.matcher(texto);
     return retorno.matches();
  }

}
```

Teste:

```
    System.out.println(Validator.validarTexto("<<<texto"));//false
    System.out.println(Validator.validarTexto("<<<texto2>>>"));//true
    System.out.println(Validator.validarTexto("<<<1texto>>"));//false
    System.out.println(Validator.validarTexto("<<<3texto2>>>"));//true
```

Teste com if:

```
String seuTexto = "<<<texto";

if (Validator.validarTexto(seuTexto)) {
  System.out.println("Texto correto.");
} else {
  System.out.println("Texto inválido.");
}
```

Comment: Yure  obrigado pela ajuda. Mas ainda tenho mais uma dúvida. Não sei se consegui explicar o que eu queria, mas é porque a minha string é um texto  que pode conter mais de um parâmetro, sendo assim como faria para guardar os parametros inválidos?

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo com uma String com mais de um parametro.

Comment: String texto = "Utilizar o <<<id>>> para realizar import. Consultar <<<tabela>>> buscando pelo <<cicurito>>>"

Comment: Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?